# Configurar cabeçalhos de página com DOMPDF

Tags: html, pdf, dompdf

Existe alguma forma de configurar o DOMPDF para que coloque um cabeçalho em todas as páginas do PDF gerado?

Estou gerando um relatório e gostaria que todas as páginas do relatório tivessem o cabeçalho da primeira.

```
    //define o estilo da página pdf
$style='
    <style>
    @page {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
#head{
background-image: url("fad.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-size: 25px;
text-align: center;
height: 60px;
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#corpo{
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
table{
border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
    padding: 3px;
}
    </style>';

//define o cabeçalho da página
$head='<div id="head">Lista de Compras</div>
<div id="corpo">';


//inclui a biblioteca do dompdf
require_once("lib/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

//recebendo os dados do Formulário
$quant=$_POST['quantidade'];
$tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
$produto=$_POST['produto'];
$obs=$_POST['obs'];

//define o corpo do documento
$body='
    <table border="1px" >
        <tr bgcolor="#ccc">
            <td>Quantidade</td>
            <td>Tipo</td>
            <td>Produto</td>
            <td>Obs.</td>
        </tr>
    ';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($quant); $i++) {
    $tmp='<tr>
        <td width="15%">'.$quant[$i].'</td>
        <td width="15%">'.$tipo[$i].'</td>
        <td width="40%">'.$produto[$i].'</td>
        <td width="30%"> '.$obs[$i].'</td>
        ';   
    $body=$body.$tmp;
}


//define o rodapé da página
$footer='
    </table>
    </div>
    ';

//concatenando as variáveis
$html=$head.$style.$body.$footer;

//gerando o pdf
$html = utf8_decode($html);
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("compras.pdf");
```

Comment: Como está seu HTML ?

Comment: @DiegoSouza, editei a pergunta e coloquei o código completo

Comment: Certo. No seu `#head`, coloca `position:fixed` e testa.

Comment: @DiegoSouza, não funcionou.

Comment: Será que não é seu cache ?

Comment: Não é, já verifiquei isso

Comment: Com o `position:fixed` coloque uma posição. `top: 10px; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto;`.

Comment: Ainda não funcionou :/

Comment: Mas vamos fazer certinho...
Igual no HTML mesmo. `<html><head><style></style></head><body></body></html>`. Quero dizer, coloca as tagas `html` e `head` e dentro de `head` coloca o `style`, mantém o `position:fixed` no `#head`.

Comment: @DiegoSouza, fiz tudo certinho e ainda assim não funcionou.

Comment: Vou simular no meu localhost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pronto.

### Mudanças

1. Coloquei as tags `html` `head` e `body` em sequência, assim como se fosse uma página `.html`.
2. Coloquei `type="text/css"`. É bom dizer ao browser especificamente o que o código é.
3. No cabeçalho `#head` adicionei `position:fixed`, é obrigatório para fixar ele em toda página. Deixei no centro da página usando o `margin: auto`, com `left: 0` e `right: 0`. `CSS` normal.
4. No `@page` que controla a estrutura da página em si, defini `120px` de topo. E defini o `margin-top` do `#head` com **-110** para o cabeçalho não subir em cima do conteúdo.
5. Coloquei o `thead` no cabeçalho da tabela para que ele se repetisse em toda página. Foi escolha minha, mas pode tirar se quiser.
6. Coloquei o `tbody` - não dentro da estrutura repetitiva - apenas para dizer ao código que a partir dali vem os dados tabulados (especificar).
7. Depois fechei lá no final as tags `body` e `html`.
8. Rodapé também deve ser `position: fixed` e **fora do corpo** do conteúdo. Assim como o cabeçalho.

---

### Código

```
<?php
     //define o estilo da página pdf
     $style='<html><head>
        <style type="text/css">
       @page {
            margin: 120px 50px 80px 50px;
        }
        #head{
            background-image: url("fad.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            font-size: 25px;
            text-align: center;
            height: 110px;
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            top: -100px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: auto;
        }
        #corpo{
            width: 600px;
            position: relative;
            margin: auto;
        }
        table{
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }
        td{
            padding: 3px;
        }
        #footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: right;
            border-top: 1px solid gray;
        }
        #footer .page:after{ 
            content: counter(page); 
        }
        </style></head><body>';

    //define o cabeçalho da página
    $head='<div id="head">Lista de Compras</div>
           <div id="corpo">';

    //inclui a biblioteca do dompdf
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

    //recebendo os dados do Formulário
    $quant      = 22;
    $tipo       = 'Unidade';
    $produto    = 'Garrafa PET';
    $obs        = 'Sem Obs';

    //define o corpo do documento
    $body='
        <table border="1px">
            <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="#ccc">
                <td>Quantidade</td>
                <td>Tipo</td>
                <td>Produto</td>
                <td>Obs.</td>
            </tr></thead><tbody>';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 130; $i++) {
        $tmp='<tr>
            <td width="15%">'.$quant.'</td>
            <td width="15%">'.$tipo.'</td>
            <td width="40%">'.$produto.'</td>
            <td width="30%"> '.$obs.'</td>';   
        $body = $body.$tmp;
    }


    //define o rodapé da página
    $footer='</tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p class="page">Página </p>
        </div></body></html>  ';

    //concatenando as variáveis
    $html=$head.$style.$body.$footer;

    //gerando o pdf
    $html = utf8_decode($html);
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("compras.pdf");

?>
```

Comment: Essa resposta me ajudou bastante, pq queria o cabeçalho da tabela em todas as páginas e as margens da folha configuradas corretamente. Porém, o cabeçalho da página ainda só aparece na primeira. Queria a logo da empresa e o título em todas as páginas.

Comment: Eu acho que você pode atualizar seu **DOMPDF**, o que acha ? Eu usei esse para simular - https://github.com/downloads/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_0-6-0_beta3.zip

Comment: Muito Obrigada!!! Era o problema da versão mesmo. Agora está perfeito!

Comment: lol. Ke luta! Ke bom que foi agora.

Comment: Aproveitando, você sabe como numerar as páginas geradas?

Comment: Sim. Primeiro você coloca esse **HTML** `<div id="footer">
      <p class="page">Página </p>
     </div>` **depois** da `</div>` que fecha a `div#corpo`. Depois acrescenta o **CSS** `#footer {
       position: fixed;
       bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: right;
       border-top: 1px solid gray;
   }
         #footer .page:after{ 
       content: counter(page); 
      }`. Coloquei uma borda cinza acima, se você não quiser só tirar o `border-top` da classe.

Comment: Alterei o código no POST para melhor visualização.

Comment: Mais uma vez, muito obrigada!

Comment: @Zoom estou com um problema parecido, pode me dar uma ajuda? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126981/33193