# Rodapé não aparece na primeira página - Laravel DomPDF

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, dompdf

Tenho o seguinte código na minha aplicação para gerar um relatório em PDF:

```
$head = '<html><head>'
      . '<title>Relatório</title><style type="text/css">'
      . '@page {margin: 120px 50px 80px 50px;}.head{font-size: 12px;height: 100px;width: 100%;position: fixed;top: -90px;left: 0;right: 0;margin: auto;}.main-content{width: 600px;position: relative;margin: auto;}.footer {font-size: 12px;position: fixed;bottom: 0;width: 100%;text-align: right;}#footer .page:after{content: counter(page); }'
      . '</style></head><body>';

$header = '<div class="head">Cabeçalho</div>';

$footer = '<div class="footer">Rodapé</div>';

$content = '<div class="main-content">'
         . '<h1 class="text-center">Relatório</h1>'
         . 'Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />'
         . '</div>';

$html = $head.$header.$content.$footer;

$pdf = \PDF::loadHTML($html);

return $pdf->stream();
```

Fiz baseado nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87008/33193), mas não sei por que motivo o rodapé não aparece na primeira página, somente da segunda em diante. O cabeçalho aparece corretamente em todas.

Estou usando Laravel 5.1 com o [laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf).

Comment: Use ID ao invés de CLASS para ver se funciona.

Comment: deu um erro: DOMNode::cloneNode(): ID head already defined

Comment: Mas é só para colocar ID no Header e no Footer. Desculpe.

Comment: mesmo assim da erro, onde eu deixo ID da esse erro. e se eu ponho class ele não poe o rodapé na primeira.

Comment: se tiver como ao menos tirar o cabeçalho também da primeira pagina somente tambem serviria

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta adicionar o conteúdo dentro da main-content, assim ele não ficará totalmente a esquerda e será mais visível, além disso no rodapé é bom colocar o z-index já que ele é fixo.

```
<div class="footer"><div class="main-content">Rodapé</div></div>


<style>
    .footer {
    font-size: 12px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    z-index: 1;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Veja se assim funciona.

```
<?php

$head = '<html><head>
         <title>Relatório</title><style type="text/css">
         @page{
            margin: 120px 50px 80px 50px;
         }
         .head{
            font-size: 12px; 
            height: 100px; 
            width: 100%; 
            position: fixed; 
            top: -90px; 
            left: 0; 
            right: 0;
            margin: auto;
          }
          .main-content{
                width: 600px; 
                position: relative;
                margin: auto;
          }
          .footer {
            font-size: 12px; 
            position: fixed; 
            bottom: 0; 
            width: 100%; 
            text-align: right;
          }
          .footer .page:after{
            content: counter(page); 
          }
          </style></head><body>';

$header = '<div class="head">Cabeçalho</div>';

$footer = '<div class="footer">Rodapé</div> </body></html>';

$content = '<div class="main-content">'
         . '<h1 class="text-center">Relatório</h1>'
         . 'Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />Conteúdo<br /><br /><br />'
         . '</div>';

$html = $head.$header.$content.$footer;

$pdf = \PDF::loadHTML($html);

return $pdf->stream();
```

Comment: Se não funcionar, é preciso usar classes mesmo. Nunca usei essa biblioteca para o Laravel.

Comment: Infelizmente continuo com o erro DOMNode::cloneNode(): ID head already defined

Comment: pois é a questão é que com classes da esse bug de não carregar o rodapé na primeira pagina, tenso...

Comment: Copia meu código e roda ele aí. Atualizei.

Comment: agora o rodapé não aparece em nenhuma pagina rs

Comment: Ah Mano... Espera.

Comment: Atualizei o código. Roda agora.

Comment: voltamos a estaca 0, primeira pagina sem o rodapé. Já revisei isso mil vezes e não encontro nada errado... to quase considerando pesquisar uma nova forma de gerar o PDF pq pode ser bug nesse domPDF que to usando.

Comment: Pode ser mesmo. No tópico que você citou que eu ajudei a menina lá era isso também.

Comment: Pois é, vou pesquisar outro aqui, caso consiga eu até posto aki depois. De qualquer forma muito obrigado @Zoom

Comment: Vou dar -1 porque chute não é proposta de resolução de problema.

Comment: @dvd obrigado zézão do asp.