# Espaçamento aumenta ao quebrar página com DomPDF

Tags: php, mysql, dompdf

Olá! Criei um contrato com DomPDF mais ao quebrar a página é aumentado o espaço sempre na primeira informação da página e assim por diante, já fiz várias modificações no meu código e não consegui tirar esse espaço. Gostaria da ajuda de alguém com olhar criterioso para ver o código.

**Segue**

```
<style>
    body{
        font-family: "Georgia" !important;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #000;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .capa{padding:5px; }
    .page_break{ page-break-before: always; }
    @page { margin: 100px 25px 100px; }
    p { margin: 0px; }

    #header {
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: -70px;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

$lista = '';
    // CONSULTA PARA BUSCAR AS CLÁUSULAS
    $sql2 = "SELECT c.*, cl.* FROM contratos c, clausula cl WHERE c.id = cl.idContrato AND c.id = ".$_GET['id']." order by cl.ordem";
    $resul2 = mysql_query($sql2, $this->conexaoMysql());

    while ($resp2 = mysql_fetch_array($resul2)) {
        // CONSULTA PARA BUSCAR OS ITENS DO CONTRATO
        $sql3 = "SELECT i.* FROM clausula cl, itens_contrato i WHERE cl.id = i.idClausula AND i.idClausula = ".$resp2['id']." ORDER BY ordem ASC, ordenar ASC";
        $resul3 = mysql_query($sql3, $this->conexaoMysql());

        $lista.=utf8_decode('
        <table width="90%" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-transform: uppercase;"><b>'.$resp2['ordem'].'. '.utf8_decode($resp2['nome_clausula']).'</b>
                <hr>
                </td>
            </tr>');
            while($resp3 = mysql_fetch_array($resul3)){
                $lista.='<tr>
                    <td width="50px;" valign="top"><b>'.$resp2['ordem'].'.'.$resp3['ordenar'].'.</b></td>
                    <td text-align="justify">'.utf8_decode($this->palavraReservada($resp3['descricao'])).'</td>
                </tr>';
            }
        $lista.='</table>';
    }
```

[image: segunda página com espaço]
Deixei com bordas pra poder ilustrar melhor.

Lembrando que me baseei [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86039/configurar-cabe%C3%A7alhos-de-p%C3%A1gina-com-dompdf).

Desde já, grato pela atenção

Comment: Pra poder ajudar na pergunta, eu gerei a página apenas no html e não apareceu nenhum espaço no final do texto, então, deve ser na hora de renderizar o código no dompdf. Se alguém conhecer alguma função para isso, agradeço muito.

Comment: Pra não deixar sem resposta, consegui resolver esse problema [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/400800/div-da-esquerda-acompanhar-altura-do-div-da-direita).